# How do I skip a piece of code if object is nil in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a piece of code that enables or disables selection lists when the appropriate checkbox is clicked, however if they are all disabled on post it will not send these in a the params list.  So I need to execute code only if they exist.

I've used:

```
if params[:id][:id2].nil?
```

and

```
if params[:id][:id2].blank?
```

also

```
if params[:id][:id2].empty?
```

not to mention simply:

```
if params[:id][:id2]
```

And all give the same error..."You have a nil object where you weren't expecting it."  How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably `params[:id]` is nil, check for `params[:id].nil?`.

**EDIT:** The comments below state correctly that `blank?` is better if you seek to evaluate against either `nil?` or `empty?`.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem.  Thanks

Comment: @travis-pessetto `.blank?` is a helper method defined in rails which converts `nil? or empty?`. What you are looking for is probably `if params[:id] && params[:id][:id2]`

Comment: What I did: Added all of my second ids in if statements nested inside the if statement of if !params[:id].blank?, while this may produce long code I find it is really easy to read, which to my employer is better as it makes it easier for anybody to maintain. Should also mention it has quite a few that have to check for both. :)...Basically the same idea as I needed to test for both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile

```
class Object
  def unless_nil(default = nil, &block)
    if nil?
      default
    else
      block[self]
    end
  end
end
```

allows things like:

```
id2 = params[:id].unless_nil { |p_id| p_id[:id2] }
id2, id3 = params[:id].unless_nil([0, 0]) { |p_id| [p_id[:id2], p_id[:id3]] }
```